# ASIHTTPFormDataRequest- "Unable to create request (bad url?)"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I have the following requirement to call a service using an ASIHTTPRequest with a POST method call. When I execute the request I get the following error:

```
errorError Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to create request (bad url?)" UserInfo=0x790b490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create request (bad url?)}
```

And heres my code:

```
   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:SampleURL]];
   [request addPostValue:@"emailid" forKey:username.text];
   [request addPostValue:@"password" forKey:password.text];
   [request addPostValue:@"first_name" forKey:first_name];
   [request addPostValue:@"last_name" forKey:last_name];
   [request addPostValue:@"option" forKey:@"userSignup"];
   request.delegate = self;
   [request startSynchronous];
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Maybe your SampleURL is a problem? Have you checked its value?

Comment: show us how **SampleURL** look like

Comment: http://112.70.02.188:51/fb/fb-webservice/fb_server.php" - sampleURL

Comment: here this same URL is working fine with ASIHTPPRequest GET Request method

Comment: check with NSLog your url Generate from string...

Answer (score 1):

`[request addPostValue:@"emailid" forKey:username.text];`

Shouldn't that be in the opposite order: `[request addPostValue:username.text forKey:@"emailid"];`

Same for the rest...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *safestring=[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:safestring];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that 'sampleURL' has some issue. What is the data type of sampleUL? it should be NSURL.
Also what is in sampleURL when this piece of code is executed.